# Adobe Flex compiler include classes

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I'm trying to create and instance of an object by reference the class object of the class using

```
getDefinitionByName()
```

the problem is that if I don't create at least one instance of the class before when try to use getDefinitionByName() it say

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable XXXXXX is not defined.
```

how can I include the class in the binary without using and instance first??, also I had tried to juts leave in the import but still don't include the class, it could be a compiler param I can pass??

I'm using Flex SDK 4.6 thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [in the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html):

`-includes class` *Links one or more classes to the resulting application SWF file, whether or not those classes are required at compile time*

Answer (score 2):

There is a bunch of compiler options which allow you to include classes, but they aren't very scalable / require some manual labour. For example, there's `-includes` option, but you must know what symbols to include. There's `-include-libraries`, but again, you'd have to compile a SWC library with the classes you need. `-include-namespace` - you'd need to write the namespace definition, listing all classes that you want to include.

Since I imagine that the task in the end will get automated one way or another, it would make more sense to just generate an AS file of the following format:

```
package your.app {
   import fully.qualified.class.Name;Name; // it is enough to just mention it
   . . .
}
```

And then include only this this class.

Comment: this is best technique imo - easier to manage than compiler options - eg: refactoring class names wont break compilation (assuming your IDE can do refactoring)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I found the solution, just add to the compiler the argument -includes like thised

-includes com.example.Myclass

that will include the class object in the binary even though u haven't used and after tried to load it with getDefinitionByName()

hopes this help to someone else, also here is a complete list of arguments for the compiler

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html